# Deploying ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment

I'm trying to deploy the default MVC project (from Visual Studio 2013) onto a remote server. They require the program to be running in Medium Trust mode, which I am having issues with. I've added `<trust level="Medium" originUrl="" />` to the `<system.web>` section of Web.config. Then when I try to run the program **on my local machine**, a SecurityException is thrown by this line:

`@Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })`

This is located in the _Layout.cshtml file, which I haven't modified from the generated template (when you create a new MVC 5 project).

My question is: what do I need to do to get my project to run in Medium Trust mode?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849801/is-trying-to-develop-for-medium-trust-a-lost-cause). It also appears that the `[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]` attribute has been removed in MVC5 which is probably the cause of the exception in the html helper

Comment: MS have also stated in [known issues](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/release-notes#knownissues) that _"ASP.NET MVC 5 no longer supports partial trust...."_ (perhaps time for a new hosting provider?)

Comment: Sigh, thanks. You're the first person who's been able to give me that reason. If you post that as an answer I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is trying to develop for Medium Trust a lost cause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849801/is-trying-to-develop-for-medium-trust-a-lost-cause)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current versions of ASP.NET now only support full trust. MS have stated in [Release Notes: Known Issues](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/release-notes#knownissues) that:

> ASP.NET MVC 5 no longer supports partial trust....

In particular the `[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]` attribute has been removed from the source code. You can read more about ASP.NET's official position in Levi's answer to [is-trying-to-develop-for-medium-trust-a-lost-cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849801/is-trying-to-develop-for-medium-trust-a-lost-cause), which also includes further links to why support has been removed.