# tilde symbol in IIS Medium Trust Environment throwing error

Tags: .net, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5

I have setup an application in Medium Trust Environment(.Net Trust Levels = Medium) and I am trying to load Favicon using Tilde(~) symbol in href but it throws an error.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/Content/img/favicon.ico"/>
```

If I remove the ~ sign then the error goes off.

I am getting error as below :

> Security Exception
>
> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not
>   allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the
>   required permission please contact your system administrator or change
>   the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the
>   permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: MVC-5 only supports full trust. Refer [this answer for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347092/deploying-asp-net-mvc-project/25354496#25354496)

Comment: If that is the case then I have to rewite many things. :(

Comment: Why do you need medium trust? The only reason you would use this is if you're using shared application pools (the default in IIS6). These days "dedicated pool per site" is the norm with your app pool/site running as "Application Pool Identity" (see also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17218344/419)

Comment: I am using GoDaddy which provides Medium Trust only :(