# Medium trust in IIS it's or not more security than Full level?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows, iis

I have an asp.net MVC 5.2 application and it is connected with a mysql database using Mysql.Data, Mysql.Data.Entity.EF6.

Previously my application were "Full" trust, but the host provider was changed to "Medium" trust.

I went search about this level, after read many docs about it, I have assumed that Medium trust is not so different than full trust, but my application does not work with this settings, I have searched for solution, but I do not have found.

Someone work with Medium level, It's really more secure than full Level?
Can I work with full level and don't worry with it?

Comment: Great it was very important ! Tks

Comment: Medium Trust is no longer supported in MVC (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347092/deploying-asp-net-mvc-project/25354496#25354496) and its links for more detail.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks a lot, that answers all!