# Asp.Net MVC Applictaion Not running on Medium Trust Level

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-hosting, visual-studio-2015, medium-trust

Trying to deploy Asp.net MVC application on Big-rock hosting Server but Big-rock hosting Server not allow `<trust level="Full"/>`.Application properly run on my local machine with `<trust level="Full"/>`.

I have placed `<trust level="Medium" />` in my web.config but after running the project give following exception:

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at
>   this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access
>   to this section using  from an
>   inherited configuration file.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34280

I want to deploy application for `<trust level="Medium" />`. If possible then what change should be needed.

Comment: Is this MVC-5? (in which case you cannot - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347092/deploying-asp-net-mvc-project/25354496#25354496))

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Yes this is MVC 5. after refer this link I found MVC5 no longer support  `<trust level="Medium" />`. So what is possible way to deploy this Application on bigRock Hosting Server.

Comment: Get them to support full trust or find another host :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Hosting Server deny to support full trust level. Is there any other solution to solve this issue or it is possible to run application with medium trust level Please guide me Thank You...

Comment: No. You will need to find someone else to host it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke You mean another hosting server..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126595/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ankush-guhe).